# Why does this only work with everything in main?

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point

So I was trying to do this challenge:
http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/1sob1e/121113_challenge_144_easy_nuts_bolts/

I wanted to use a text file for the input.
The code I have works if I copy the contents of the separate functions I am using into main but otherwise it doesn't seem to run anything after a call to either the readall or compare functions. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//variable declarations
int i;
int n;
struct item *prices;

//function declarations
void readall();
int compare(int i);
int fail();

//structure definitions
struct item{
    char *name;
    int price;
};

//main
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    if(fail()){
        printf("Input not found\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        readall();
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            if(compare(i)){
                printf("%s\n",prices[i].name); //not added price change yet
            }
        }
    }
free(prices);
return 0;
}

//functions
void readall(){
    FILE *input = fopen("input.txt","r");
    int n=0;
    fscanf(input,"%u",&n);
    struct item prices[2*n-1];
    malloc(sizeof(prices));
    for(i=0;i<2*n;i++){
        fscanf(input,"%ms",&prices[i].name);
        fscanf(input,"%u",&prices[i].price);
    }
    fclose(input);
}

int fail(){
    FILE *input = fopen("input.txt","r");
    fclose(input);
    if(input==NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int compare(int i){
    if(prices[i].price==prices[i+n].price){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
return 2;
}
```

On a side note from running under valgrind I can see that I am clearly not handling memory properly so any tips on that and/or any other constructive criticism would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to compile and link the separate files.  Show us the command you use for that.

Comment: It will be surpraising if you got an solution for it here! http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: @PaulBeckingham I compiled it using `cc -Wall -g NandB.c -o NandB`

Comment: You mention multiple files, but I only see one in the command.  You have two problems: the code above is flawed (@James points out why), and your other issue regarding multiple files needs more information - what's in the other file, for example, and how did you compile/link it.

Comment: Minor: Re: `int n=0; fscanf(input,"%u",&n);`.  Better to use `unsigned n=0;` or `fscanf(input,"%d",&n);`.

Comment: @PaulBeckingham The other file is a text file in the same directory called input.txt and it contains first the number of items in the list and then then the names of each item with their initial price followed by the names of each item with their final price. For example `2 CarriageBolt 45 Eyebolt 50 CarriageBolt 45 Eyebolt 45` The program is supposed to look for which prices have changed. I have only referred to it within NandB.c

Comment: No, I'm referring to the other source file.

Answer (score 3):

Your readall function is wrong. What you're doing is creating an array on the stack, then mallocing a separate array on the heap, which has no name and so is never used and leaked. Try

```
Prices = malloc(sizeof(item) * n);
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two immediate problems:

1. The `prices` array is allocated on the stack and your subsequent
   use of `malloc()` makes no sense. Use something like this:

   ```
   item* prices = malloc ((2*n-1) * sizeof(struct item));
   ```
2. Within the scope of `readall()`, you define a variable `n` which
   shadows the global variable of the same name. Only the local `n` is
   filled using `fscanf()`. The later call to `compare()`, however,
   accesses the global `n` which has not been initialized.

You should try to give variables meaningful names rather
than `i`, `n`, or `x`. At least do this for variables with a
meaningful lifetime of more than a few lines of code. (In my opinion,
using single-character variable names is okay for simple loops.)